# What is the complexity of the function f(n) = f(n-1)+f(n-2)+f(n-3)+...+1

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the time complexity to compute this function for n.

```
int rec(int n)
{
    if (n<=1) {
        return n ;
    }
    int i;
    int sum=0;
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
       sum=sum+rec(i); 
    }
    return sum ;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

well let's break this out

```
 (1)        f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + ... f(1) + 1
```

however,

```
 (2)        f(n-1) = f(n-2) + ... f(1) + 1
```

so plugging (2) into (1) gives

```
 (3)        f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) = 2 f(n-1)
```

and f(2) = 1, so this is clearly 2<sup>n</sup> (for details: [Can not figure out complexity of this recurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423832/can-not-figure-out-complexity-of-this-recurrence/14424445#14424445)).  well, actually 2<sup>n-1</sup> but in big O, it doesn't quite matter because the <sup>-1</sup> is the same as /2.

Comment: Excellent answer I must say. Thanks a lot

Comment: Excellent, I like it, but isn't it actually a **non**-answer to the question? You just demonstrated that the O(n^2) recursive algorithm as written above blows and that a linear algorithm is possible. Don't get me wrong, this is actually better than an answer.

Comment: @doomster, that is a very astute observation.  I suspect that OP used that function only to illustrate this particular type of run time, and that the *actual* function (not shown here) is one in which other work gets done at each recursive call.  It's somewhat of a farce that the function returns its run time (number of + it uses).  After all, why wouldn't you just analytically compute the run time and return it since a closed-form formula exists.  That aside, there is a recursive coolness in this function despite being inefficient: *a function that returns its runtime*.